# WPF TreeView not displaying arrow

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm having a weird problem that I can't figure out where it's coming from.

I'm binding a TreeView in WPF to an object structure. At the beginning, the TreeView is completely empty, then I create the root with empty children (from a user action) and then the children are added (also from a user action).

For some reason that I don't understand, when I add the children of the root (Parents in my example), the arrow is not added to the root element. The parents are there, because when I double-click the root, it displays the parents, but the arrow is not displayed.

At the same time, the parents have "Children" and for those there is no issue, the arrow is displayed and everything is fine.

Here's the (simplified) XAML I used to display the TreeView:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate"
                      DataType="dom:Child">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Child: " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ParentTemplate"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}"
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}"
                                  DataType="dom:Parent">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Parent: " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Point, StringFormat='point: {0:N2}'}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="RootTemplate" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parents}" 
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ParentTemplate}"
                                  DataType="vm:RootViewModel">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Root: " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5 0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Roots}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RootTemplate}">
       <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTreeViewItem}">
             <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
          </Style>
       </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
 </Grid>
```

In terms of ViewModel, there is nothing particular. The ViewModel has a collection of Root elements (called Roots, which is bound to the ItemSource). And this Roots class has a collection of Parent called Parents which have a collection of Child called Children. Parents implement INotifyPropertyChanged which notifies when I add a child, same thing for Root.

[image: Example of the result]

Comment: can you add some screenshots?

Comment: Try setting the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.DataType` properties on your `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s.

Comment: Added the screenshot, tested with setting the DataType, doesn't change the result.

Comment: What are the types of your collections? Are you using ObservableCollection<>? If not, then I suspect WPF isn't getting notified when the collection changes.

Comment: @JoelLucsy spot on, it was actually an IEnumerable. I just tested with ObservableCollection and it's working correctly.
Kind of annoying though, because the Parents and Childs are in my domain, and I wanted to not let the user be able to add items without passing through a method in my class. Is there a "ReadOnlyObservableCollection" or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should really be closed, but just in case someone else looks at this:

Joel Lucsy comment solved the issue.

In addition: [read only observable collection on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).